# PHP - ERROR 1064 in mysqli trying making a select query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm a new user of this website.
I'm trying to execute this simple query:

```
$id_book=$_REQUEST['id_book'];
$date=date("Y/m/d");
$sql="INSERT INTO books(id_book,date) VALUES($id_book,'$date')";
if(!$mysqli->query($sql)){
   die($mysqli->error.". ".$mysqli->errno);
};
```

but got this error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''2019/02/27')' at line 1. 1064

What am I doing wrong? Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 3):

First, DO NOT inject that `$_REQUEST['id_book']` variable into your SQL, see [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and use a prepared statement.

You need to use the correct [DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) format for MySQL:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");
```

Also `date` is a reserved word in MySQL, so choose something else for the column name or use backticks:

```
// placeholders for prepared statement ?
$sql = "INSERT INTO books(id_book, `date`) VALUES(?, ?)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting proprly the date string in date

```
$sql="INSERT INTO books(id_book,date) VALUES($id_book,str_to_date('$date', '%Y/%m/%d')";
```

anyway you should not use php var in sql  .. you are at risk for sqlinjection .. for avoid this take a look at you msysql driver for prepared statement and binding param